# Why are continuous functions not dense in $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Why are the continuous functions not dense in $L^\infty$?

I mean both concretely (i.e. a counter example) and intuitively why is this the case.

Answer (score 49):

Consider 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<0\\1&\text{if }x\ge 0.\end{cases}$$
Any continuous $g$ with $\|f-g\|_\infty<\frac 13$ must have $g(x)<f(x)+\frac13=\frac13$ for all $x<0$. By continuity, $g(0)\le \frac13$, contradicting $g(0)>f(0)-\frac13=\frac 23$.

Even if we only require $|f(x)-g(x)|<\frac13$ for almost all $x$, the argument above still  holds (with using continuity on the right as well).

Intuitively, the continuous $g$ cannot do the jump at once, it needs some "preparation" and "relaxation".

Comment: In other words, the topology on $L^{\infty}$ is strictly finer than its restriction to $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 34):

If a convergent sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly then the limiting function is continuous. Consequently, the only functions which can be approximated to arbitrary accuracy in $L^\infty$ by continuous functions are the continuous functions. In other words, the subspace of $L^\infty$ consisting of continuous functions is closed.

Of course, there are many functions in $L^\infty$ which are not continuous!

Comment: Awesome intuition! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof using separability.
$C(\mathbb R^n)$ is separable, whereas $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is not. From this, it follows that $C(\mathbb R^n)$ is not dense in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

One can use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to prove that $C(\mathbb R^n)$ is separable.
To prove that $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is not separable, consider the following collection $\mathscr A := \{\chi_{B_{r}(0)}\}_{r > 0}$, where $\chi_{B_{r}(0)}$ is the usual indicator function.
Notice that $\mathscr A$ is an uncountable subset of $L^\infty$ with $\|f - g\|_\infty = 1$ for any $f, g \in \mathscr A$ such that $f\ne g$.
Then for any dense subset $\mathscr D$ of $L^\infty$, one can define an injection $\mathscr A \hookrightarrow \mathscr D$ (for each $f \in \mathscr A$, choose $f^* \in \mathscr D$ such that $\|f - f^*\|_\infty < 1/2$).