# From $C[0, 1]$ to $L^\infty [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am dealing with the following exercise:

Let $u_n$ bounded in $L^\infty[0,1]$ such that, for any continuous function $f: [0,1]\times R$ to $R$
$$\lim_n \int_0^1 f(x, u_n(x))=\int_0^1 f(x, u(x)).$$

Prove that $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $L^1.$
There is a hint saying to prove it first for $u\in C^0$.

I succeeded in proving it for $u$ continuous, choosing $f(x, y)=|y- u(x)|$, but I don't know how to get to $L^\infty$.

My idea was to approximate $u$ in $L^1$ with continuous functions, (while continuous functions are not dense in $L^\infty$, right?), but I can't see how to work out details.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To approximate $u$ in $L^1$ with continuous functions, first given any $\epsilon >0$, we choose $u_{\epsilon }$ to be a continuous function such that $\|u_{\epsilon }-u\|_1<{\epsilon }$ and setting $f(x, y)=|y- u_{\epsilon }(x)|$ just like your idea, then you will get 
$$\lim_n \|u_n- u_{\epsilon }\|_1=\|u- u_{\epsilon }\|_1$$

Finally, we use the triangle inequality argument

$$\lim_n \|u_n- u\|_1\leq\lim_n \|u_n- u_{\epsilon }\|_1+\|u- u_{\epsilon }\|_1=2\|u- u_{\epsilon }\|_1<2\epsilon $$

then you're done.

Comment: The existence of $u_{\epsilon }$ is follows by two facts, "$C^0[0,1]$ is $L^1$-dense in $L^1[0,1]$" and "$L^{\infty}[0,1]\subset L^1[0,1]$"

Comment: Many thanks @yoyo ! Just a doubt: Actually the $L^\infty$ boundedness of $u_n$ is useless?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Because I can't find something wrong in my proof either. But I geuss the boundedness of $u_n$ may use in a more general proof such like some statement without the condition $\lim_n \int_0^1 f(x, u_n(x))=\int_0^1 f(x, u(x))$, and the boundedness is used to prove it by Dominated Convergence Theorem (maybe).

Answer (score 4):

On a finite measure space $(X,\mu)$, $L^q(X) \subset L^p(X)$ for $q\geq p$. This is proved by Holder's inequality. Apply this to be able to approximate your $L^\infty$ functions.

Comment: [Are you sure](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221069/why-are-continuous-functions-not-dense-in-l-infty)?

Comment: @ClementC. Giant Tortoise did not specify density with respect to what. You are right in that they are not dense for the norm $L^{\infty}$, but they are probably referring to the $L^1$ norm (which is the only thing needed for the purposes for the question)

Comment: The use of "dense in $L^\infty$" is very misleading, then -- from your comment, you mean "dense in $L^\infty$ [seen as a subset of $L_1$, for the $L_1$ norm]," while the most natural (and I'd argue only natural) interpretation is "dense in $L^\infty$ [for the obvious norm on $L^\infty$ which is a normed space, so the $L^\infty$ norm]"

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, will clean up the answer.