# Existence of a functional on $L^\infty$ that vanish on C(X)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hahn-banach-theorem

So I want to prove the existence of a functional on $L^\infty(0,1)$ that vanish on C(X). I looked up and there is one example, but not much explanation. So we consider the continuous functions that have equal limits when x tends to 0 and 1. And take the functional that maps a function to the difference of two limits. And then extend it to the whole space.

However, it only vanishes on the set of continuous functions that have equal limits. Can you help me explain why does it vanishes on all continuous ones? I think this is wrong, do you know other examples?

Comment: $C(X)$ means $C(0,1)\cap L^\infty (0,1)$?

Comment: You can use the second "important consequence"  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Important_consequences) for existence.

Comment: Yes weiyi sun. It is

Comment: Do you know any text that Ican read the proof of this great consequence?

Comment: Using the notation of the link: Set $M=z+U$ and $f(u+\alpha z)=\alpha$ for $u$ in $M$, $\alpha\in \Bbb R$. This is a non-zero linear functional on $M$. Extend using HB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the span of $C[0,1]$ and some particular member of $L^\infty(0,1)$ that is not in  $C[0,1]$,
e.g. $I_{[0,1/2]}$, the indicator function of $[0, 1/2]$.  Define a bounded linear functional $\varphi$ on
$V$ by $\varphi(f + t I_{[0,1/2]}) = t$.  Then extend to $L^\infty(0,1)$ by Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Why is this functional $\varphi$ continuous?

Comment: I try to show this in the following way: $|\varphi(f+tI_{[0,1/2]})|\leq  \dfrac{\|f+tI_{[0,1/2]}\|}{\|f/t+I_{[0,1/2]}\|}$ and shows that $\|f/t+I_{[0,1/2]}\|>1/3$ for any $t\neq 0$ and any continuous $f$.

Comment: If $W$ is a closed subspace of Banach space $X$, and $u \notin W$, let $d > 0$ be the distance from $u$ to $W$.  Then the linear functional on $\text{span}(u,W)$ defined by $\varphi(tu + w) = t$ for $w \in W$ has norm at most $1/d$ because $ \|t u + w\| \ge d |t|$, i.e. $|\varphi(tu+w)| = |t| \le d^{-1} \|tu+w\|$.

Comment: Nice, so by choosing $w_0\in W$ s.t $d=\|w_0-u\|$ and putting $g=d^{-1}(u-w_0)$, we have that $\|g\|=d^{-1}d=1$ and $\varphi(g)=d^{-1}$. As a consequence $\|\varphi\|=d^{-1}$.  Am I correct?

Comment: Not quite.  In general there may not be such a $w_0$, just a sequence such $w_n$ such that $\|w_n - u\| \to d$.

Comment: A last question: in the above question $w_0\equiv 1/2$ is a minimizer   which realize $1/2=d=(I_{[0,1/2]},C([0,1])$. Is this ok? I  am using  a variiation of this answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221069/why-are-continuous-functions-not-dense-in-l-infty.   To conclude that $\|f-I_{[0,1/2]} \| \geq 1/2$.